# Implementing multi threading in python to to read the lines in a file and check whether the line matches the given string

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am trying to implement multi-threading in python3 to read the lines in a particular file and check whether the line matches the given string. This is causing me some confusion. Please help me with this and also let me know if multi-processing used here instead of multiprocessing. Please check the code below

One more thing. I am trying to implement this on Linux based system

```
import threading 
from subprocess import check_output

def thread_task(line): 


    try:
        if line=="hello123":
            print("Found")
            init_.close()
            exit()
    except:
                                #print("Somethings gotta")
        pass


def check_point(lock,file1):
    lock.acquire()
    print(file1)
    with open(file1,"r",encoding="utf-8",errors = "ignore") as data:
            for line in data:
                line = line[:-1]
                thread_task(line)
    lock.release()

def main_task(wordlist):
    lock = threading.Lock() 

    # creating threads
    t = list(range(0,len(div)))
    for i in t: 
            t[i] = threading.Thread(target=check_point, args=(lock,div[i],))

    # start threads 
    for i in range(0,len(div)): 
        t[i].start()

    # wait until threads finish their job
    for i in range(0,len(div)): 
        t[i].join()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    wordlist = input("Enter the File location : ")
    div = check_output(['split','-l','100000',wordlist,"Temp/"])
    div = check_output(["ls",'Temp/']).decode("utf").split("\n")
    div = div[:-1]  
    main_task(div)
    print("String Not found")
```

Comment: Have you tried using the multiprocessing library (with a multiprocessing.Queue()) object? [(A link to the documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, unfortunately your question is lacking. what are you trying to do? what have you tried? what errors are you getting? show some code

Comment: Sir, I am editing my post. Please recheck it once.

Answer (score 1):

In most OS the bottleneck is the disk access. Therefore splitting your large file into many small files to read them simultaneously is just a waste of time.

Please, read your file in your python script, one line at a time, check for the word being included or not. Multiprocessing won't help you here.

---

If I were you, I'd write something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wordlist = set()
    wordlist_name = input("Enter the File location : ")
    with open( wordlist_name ) as fin :
        wordlist = set( fin.read().split() )

    if 'hello123' in wordlist :
        print( "Found" )
    else :
        print("String Not found")
```

Comment: Sir, Does multi-threading can be implemented here?

Comment: @B.Lakshmipathi yes, it can be implemented. the gains would be negligible and the amount of work will be much larger. there's no point in multu-threading or multiprocessing if the bottleneck is the disk IO access.

Comment: @B.Lakshmipathi see the updated answer for more info

Comment: SIr, I am trying to create a script that can crack password-protected zip file. So, That is the reason why I wanted to implement multi-threading

Comment: @B.Lakshmipathi there are plenty of very fast zip password crackers that are written in C or C++ (much faster than Python), and use advanced methods, besides a dictionary attack. please, use Google to find them and use them instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to choose between multiprocessing and multi-threading you may be better off using multiprocessing in this case. Your program would then look something like this-

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process_line(line):
    if(line.strip() == "hello123"):
        return True
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(4)
    wordlist = input("Enter the File location : ")
    with open(wordlist) as source_file:
        results = pool.map(process_line, source_file, 4)
    if True in results:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("string not found")
```

Though depending on your system this might not help at all since in this case your reading from a file you tend to be I/O bound

Comment: for a million line file your code will create 250.000 (that's 250 thousands!!!) processes. how wonderful! nice optimization! =)

Comment: @lenik I agree this is a quick and dirty implementation, It just outlines how the library can be implemented (as that was what the initial issue seemed to be). The split of lines can also be quite easily changed.

Comment: @lenik also why would it make 250k processes ? the number of processes in pool is set to 4 from `pool = Pool(4)`

Comment: `4` in the line `results = pool.map(process_line, source_file, 4)` is the chunk size. which means, the file will be split into 4-words chunks. 1e6 / 4 = 250.000

Comment: @lenik thats for the size of the chunks thats preloaded, yes the file is split into 250k parts (for a 1 mil line file) there are still only 4 processes